# Execute all the procedure in plsql block .Even if on proc has error inside it

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have 3 procedure which are called inside PLSQL block.
Procedure 1 has exceptional handling inside it.
Procedure 2 does not have exceptional handling inside it.
Procedure 3 has exceptional handling inside it.

When plsql block is executed.Purposely in proc 2, i kept error like condition. 
So proc 1 runs successfully and updates table.
Proc 2 throws some error Because of error in proc 2 ,proc 3 also does not run

So i want to bypass the error like condition

1) I have tried exception handling in plsql block

2) Pragma autonomous transation.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC1 AS ----HAS EXCEPTIONAL HADLING
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMP
SET ENAME='uMANG_17'
WHERE EMPNO=7369;

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Ignore all exceptions and return control to calling block
        NULL;
END PROC1;
```

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC2 AS ----DOES NOT HAVE EXCEPTIONAL HADLING
BEGIN
 UPDATE EMP
SET ENAME='ROHAN_02'
WHERE HIREDATE='7499';

COMMIT;

END PROC2;
```

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC3 AS ----HAS EXCEPTIONAL HADLING
BEGIN

UPDATE EMP
SET ENAME='JATIN_10'
WHERE EMPNO=7521;

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Ignore all exceptions and return control to calling block
        NULL;
END PROC3;
```

```
BEGIN
PROC1;---has update statement
PROC2;--- has error like condition
PROC3;-- has update statement
END;
/
```

1) ALL 3 procs should update.

2)The above code runs but it does not update PROC 3.

3)ALL the proc should run in plsql block eeven in error like contiobion.

Comment: _" I have tried exception handling in plsql block"_  and what was the problem?

Comment: PROC 2 does not have exceptional handling .It terminates the block

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it in pl/SQL block

```
BEGIN
  PROC1;---has update Statement

  begin
    PROC2;--- has error like condition
  exception
    when others then
      -- do something
  end;

  PROC3;-- has update statement
END;
/
```

Comment: I have purposely did not mentioned plsql block in PROC 2.

Comment: it is not clear what you what, if this is not what you are looking for

Comment: I am looking to bypass the error in plsql block even if any of the procs fail.PROC 2 fails but PROC3 should run and fire update statment

Comment: so whats wrong in my example? you can handle exeption inside your proc  like in  proc1 or proc3 or outside like in my example  for proc2

Comment: So its compulsary to add exceptional handling in all procs..ok thanks!!

Comment: Alternatively, you can of course call it in separate processes and if the process with proc2 runs on error, the process with proc 3 can still be executed.

However, the errors should be treated in any case, so that the process can be ended in a controlled manner

Comment: If you can call the procedures dynamically using a list of names, you could write your controlling procedure as a loop instead of 50 separate calls.

Comment: @umangrathod I too faced this issue, did you found any proper solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the exceptions while calling the procedures. PL/SQL compiler end the execution as soon as it faces an error irrespective being in the calling procedure or called procedure. So you have to end up with code as -

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
         PROC1;
    EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
             NULL;
    END;
    BEGIN
         PROC2;
    EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
             NULL;
    END;
    BEGIN
         PROC3;
    EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
             NULL;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: I have more then 50 procs in this plsql block So shall i write 50 exceptionalblock?

Comment: You have no other option I guess.